# PHP: Echo next 2 lines after finding one

Tags: php

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("wqer.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
      if(preg_match("/aut/i", $line)){
      **echo fgets($handle).fgets($handle);**
      } 
    }
} else {
    echo "Error loading file.";
}
?>
```

The textfile wqer.txt looks something like that (but it has 12k lines :D):

```
bike
*aut*
car
ball
mouse
*aut*
light
house
```

I want from this script to echo next 2 lines after finding the **aut** line from this file.
So the output should look like this:

```
car
ball
light
house
```

Yep sorry, house should be the last one.
Solved, many thanks to Wrikken, simple solution, I almost feel embarrased :)

Comment: did you mean `car ball light house` as the output?

Comment: So, `echo fgets($handle).fgets($handle);`?

Comment: mouse should be rename to house in the last line of your description

Comment: @Wrikken I believe you may need to include `"\n"` after each `fgets` call.

Comment: Make it into an array, then you will have a line id. Then you can echo `$line_id + 1` and `$line_id + 2`?

Comment: @LoganMurphy: nope, not in my PHP I don't. Does your `fgets` not return the `\n` that's already there in the file?

Comment: @Wrikken you are right, the new line is include, i was just making sure since other languages do work that way ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$found = 0;
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    if(preg_match("/aut/i", $line)){
       $found = 2;
       continue; // if you don't want "aut" to be printed. remove otherwise.
    }
    if ($found > 0) {
      echo $line;
      $found--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add error checking:

```
$lines = file("wqer.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$lines = array_map('trim', $lines); //in case there are spaces etc. that are not shown

foreach($lines as $key => $val) {
    if($val == '*aut*') {  //(stripos($val, 'aut') !== false) //to keep similar to how you have it now
        echo $lines[$key+1] . "\n" . $lines[$key+2] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this just seems a bit more versatile but Marcs' solution would be less resource intensive for sure.